# Python-3.x SIMPLE XPath Library

Tags: python, xpath, python-3.x

I am trying to parse quite simple XML using Python.

Before Python 3 I used "webscraping" library with XPath functionality.
Works very simple:

```
xpath.search(xml (xml string), "XPath Query (//search)"
```

- returns found elements based on provided XPath query.

Now I have decided to switch to Python 3, and library mentioned above doesn't work properly with it (even after 2to3.py) - so I decided to use native `xml.etree.ElementTree` library.

Probably I don't understand something, but this is proper nightmare. It doesn't work in the way where you simple provide XML and XPath query into the function and it returns results. Instead, you need to use 10+ lines of code, messing with element's children etc. and it still doesn't work...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.fromstring(xml)
result = doc.findall("//XPath Query")
```

returns `SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element`
Adding `.` to `//XPath Query` doesn't help a lot either.

Is there some kind of reason why `ElementTree` and `lxml` libraries are so complicated and don't allow to SIMPLE use XPATH instead of messing around with elements, using `for` loop every time etc?

Could anyone recommend simple library for python 3 which will just use XPath Query and return result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example xml from http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html, searching seems to work fine:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> xml = """..."""
>>> doc = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> doc.findall(".//rank")
[<Element 'rank' at 0x10199ebd0>, <Element 'rank' at 0x10199e210>, <Element 'rank' at 0x10199e4d0>]
```

Or if you want to search from root explicitly:

```
>>> ET.ElementTree(doc).findall('//rank')
```

Comment: `doc.findall("country")`
This is not XPath query I am afraid. And If you will want to search something that is not direct children of the root, it won't find it as far as I can see.

Comment: Well, xpath works as well, and I added both a relative and absolute matching; the absolute path gives a warning but works.

Comment: `ET.ElementTree(doc).findall('//rank')`
Even despite the fact it now accepts XPath query (with warning), it still returns empty list after XPath query performed. 

Probably this is something to do with the layout / format of my XML itself. But there is nothing I can do because XML source comes from eBay API, which will be very difficult to pre-format, so that ElementTree will be happy with it. I still in situation where I can't use any of the available XPath parsers for python 3.x without warnings and SIMPLE clean syntax to parse XML. I guess I will have to switch back to python 2.7 for now.

Comment: After some time playing with ElementTree and lxml, I can more or less understand it with all the namespaces and other features. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem now.

My XML response contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <!-- Call-specific Output Fields -->
  <HasMoreOrders> boolean </HasMoreOrders>
  <OrderArray> OrderArrayType
    <Order> OrderType
      <AdjustmentAmount currencyID="CurrencyCodeType"> AmountType (double) </AdjustmentAmount>
      <AmountPaid currencyID="CurrencyCodeType"> AmountType (double) </AmountPaid>
      <AmountSaved currencyID="CurrencyCodeType"> AmountType (double) </AmountSaved>
      <BuyerCheckoutMessage> string </BuyerCheckoutMessage>
      <BuyerUserID> UserIDType (string) </BuyerUserID>
      <CheckoutStatus> CheckoutStatusType
      ...
```

After parsing that XML:

```
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
result = tree.findall("*")
```

It returns EVERY single element with prefix `{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}`

For example, if I need to search for `<BuyerCheckoutMessage>`

`result = tree.findall(".//BuyerCheckoutMessage")` it will return nothing, because that element looks like `{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}BuyerCheckoutMessage`.

Therefore, to search for elements, I need to include `{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}` before every XPath query in order to retrieve my element.

So the solution is to use :

`result = tree.findall(".//{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}BuyerCheckoutMessage")`
`result[0].text` will return the elements value.

Why it just doesn't work the way of ET.search(xml, "XPath-query") is the biggest secret for me. So much time wasted.

Comment: What you want is easy, not simple. XML is a lot of things, but not simple. If no namespace is given, XPath should assume that it has no namespace. It is possible to register shortcuts for long namespaces using ET.register_namespace, to make the queries less verbose.